# document.getElementById().value var + nod working

Tags: javascript

hello everyone so i want to make this part easier for the problem but i can't

need to change the following this code works

```
setTimeout(

    function() {
document.getElementById("coordinateTargetFirstTime").value = "427|501";}, (Math.random() * 1000) + 3000);
```

and change to

var template = "427|501";

```
setTimeout(

    function() {
document.getElementById("coordinateTargetFirstTime").value = " + template";}, (Math.random() * 1000) + 3000);
```

this code nod working help me thanx (+ template) is show + teplated ( nod 427|501 )

Comment: You have `template` as a String. You want to assign a variable, like:`.value = template;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting the variable sourrounded by double quoutes which makes it a string.

try this: `document.getElementById("coordinateTargetFirstTime").value = template;`

By the way where working with the dom I recomend using jQuery since it cross browser compatible and in this case it has a method called `.val()` or you can also use `setAttribute('value')`

Hope it works, cheers

Answer (score 1):

As Iban has said you are making the template var a string. To enhance your readability maybe break it out as described below:

```
var template = ""
function run(template) {
    let id = document.getElementById("elementid")
    let result = id.value + template
    return result
}

let timeout = (Math.random() * 1000) + 3000)

setTimeout(run(template), timeout);
```